# Output assembly files with OASIS

Tags: ocaml, oasis

Is there a way to keep the assembly files when building with OASIS?

I'm looking for something simpler than directly using `ocamlopt -S`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NativeOpt` field to specify this flag:

```
Executable "prog"
  Path:           src
  MainIs:         main.ml
  Install:        true
  NativeOpt:      -S
  CompiledObject: best
```